# How often does outlook.live.com service sync my external feeds?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, calendar

not sure this is the right community to ask my question

I subscribed to some external calendars (Google, OwnCloud) in my Microsoft online Outlook account and wonder how often does online Outlook service pull updates from external sources?

The synchronization with my desktop/cellphone client works fine. But schedules from external calendars often appear 12h hours later.

Is there any reliable information available about the sync frequency of that pulling service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comments of the previous answer by @harrymc he pointed me to a blog entry of [support.office.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-or-subscribe-to-a-calendar-in-outlook-com-cff1429c-5af6-41ec-a5b4-74f2c278e98c) where they write, I'm quoting:

> Subscribing to an iCal online calendar connects it to your calendar. Whenever the owner of an iCal you've subscribed to makes changes to the events, Outlook.com updates your calendar. This is a good way to track events that change frequently, like movie times or a school calendar.
>
> **Note**: This update can take more than 24 hours, although updates should happen approximately every 3 hours.

So I will mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

For Outlook, if you do *Send / Receive*, this will sync the calendars as well.

To adjust that interval go to *File > Options > Advanced*, scroll down to
"Send and receive", and click the button *Send/Receive...*
where you may adjust "Schedule an automatic send/receive every...".

Comment: the sync of my online calendar with my desktop/cellphone works fine. But,  I subscribed to external Calendars (.ics calendar) in my online account and those are not synced at Send/Receive operation I think. I will add this information to my question.

Comment: Are these imported `.ics` files?

Comment: Google shares a link for each calendar, not sure which format. OwnCloud uses CalDav. One external calendar is a .ics file.

Comment: If you have *subscribed* to the calendar then this should work. See [Import or subscribe to a calendar in Outlook.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-or-subscribe-to-a-calendar-in-outlook-com-cff1429c-5af6-41ec-a5b4-74f2c278e98c).

Comment: Thank you for the provided link. There I found the info how long it takes :)   :   `This update can take more than 24 hours, although updates should happen approximately every 3 hours.`

Comment: This works fine in theory and may even work for some cases, but don't count on it. See for example [post1](https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/954580?hl=en) and [post2](https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/12658899?hl=en).